# Display offset coordinates of expand/collapse section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sections

I have a `expand/collapse` section in my web page. The expand/collapse is done using `section` not `div/table`. My code is:

```
<section id="examples">
    <text id = "ui-examples">
        <p class="the-data">Of course you can add other text before, after, and around the elements described in the previous section.</p>
    </text>
</section>
```

On loading the page there happens many instances of `the-data`, so the `ui-examples` gets loaded with different ids and corresponding `the-data`. How can I get those different `text ids` to calculate the `offset` coordinates of each `text`?

**EDIT formatting**

Comment: Just a quick note, if there are many instances of "examples" as an ID, then you should be using a class instead. An ID is a unique identifier for one HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**The HTML**

```
<section class="examples">
    <text class="ui-examples">
        <p class="the-data">Of course you can add other text before, after, and around the elements described in the previous section.</p>
    </text>
</section>
```

**And the jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.examples').each(function() {
        var theData = $(this).find('.the-data');
        console.log(theData.offset().left);
        console.log(theData.offset().top);
    });
});
```

This is first waiting for the document to be ready, once it is it then loops through each div that has a class of "example" inside that loop we use the `find` jQuery function that will search all children of the current div (in this case it is one instance of `.example`) that match the selector. So by using `.the-data` it will find the paragraph tag you are looking for.

You can then use `offset()` to get the co ordinates.

Comment: It will do, but it is not good practice to have multiple ID's on one page. You should use classes instead. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id